# StackExchange overlay can't practically be used with a straight mouse cursor movement

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

The mouse cursor movement required with the new layout is not straight: I now need to avoid the triangle of dismissal.

### After

[image]

### Before

[image]

As this is how I frequently switch between Meta and non-Meta, I have for now opt-out of the new layout.

ps: did LinkedIn just changed from White to Black while StackExchange is changing from Black to White?